# Xcode 9 perform a custom command on clean

Tags: xcode, xcode9

I need to run a custom shell script on the clean step in Xcode (Xcode 9 to be exact). I have a set of makefiles that build my dependencies, initially I was calling this script in the run script phase, but then the outputs of these makefiles never get cleaned. So I though that if I handled the Xcode environemnt variable `${ACTION}` in this script then it could also clean them. The issue is - the script is not called on clean.

There were several posts regarding this so here is what I've tried:

1. Making an additional aggregate target. I added the target and put a script that handles `${ACTION}` from the build environment, but that script is never executed upon clean. When cleaning there is only a `Clean.remove clean` line in build log.
2. Making an external build system target (some older posts stated an external script target, but I could not find that in Xcode 9). This then allows me to execute a custom script (if I replace the default `/usr/bin/make` command to my script), but in this case the `${ACTION}` environment variable is not set (I verified this in the build output, it always has `export ACTION=` in it), thus I cannot distinguish between clean and build phases.

Regarding the aggregate target, it has the output files property, if I specify them - could that make Xcode clean them?

Comment: Did you figure this one out? This appears to still be an issue. The custom scripts are not executed on a clean.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Run script during Clean / Clean All in Xcode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1903890/run-script-during-clean-clean-all-in-xcode)

Comment: For future readers, this is basically a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1903890/run-script-during-clean-clean-all-in-xcode

Answer (score 0):

A bit of a zombie, but closest to the issue that I am seeing.  This appears to be a bug in the new build system.  Using the old build system, the action is set.  Two options here:

1. Use the Legacy build system.
2. Use separate external targets that call your script and manually pass the action parameter required and swap schemes manually as needed.